# How to post form data from razor view to WebApi as dictionary?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-web-api, forms, http-post

I have a lot of forms created with helper

```
Html.BeginRouteForm
```

I want to post it to my web api controller and I can do it with predefined DTO.

But I want to post it as dictionary, because the forms is for getting parameters from user. In each case the set of parameters can be different.

How I can do it?
How I can do it better?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Here is my form:

```
     @using (Html.BeginRouteForm("DefaultApi", new { controller = "Products", action = "Add", httproute = "true" }))
        {
            <div class="form-group">
                Product:
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Product, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                Cost:
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Cost, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        }
```

Comment: What makes you think you want a dictionary (and what would be the point). You view is based on a model, so the POST method just needs a parameter `MyModel model` where `MyModel` is the model you declare in the view and it will be correctly bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare the parameter in the post action as a [FormDataCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.formatting.formdatacollection(v=vs.118).aspx) which is derived from NameValueCollection and is very similar to a dictionary. This is the weakly typed method to post form data in MVC.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(FormDataCollection formDataCollection)
{
    var nvc = formDataCollection.ReadAsNameValueCollection(); 
    foreach(var key in nvc)
    {
        var value = nvc[key];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried it and it's not work for me. I will update my post

Comment: In my case length of formCollection.AllKeys length is 0. I also experimented with [FromBody] attibute.

Comment: Your question clearly states it but I missed that you are using Web API instead of MVC. Try changing FormCollection to FormDataCollection. You may need to add a reference to System.Net.Http.Formatting. See also http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/589f6915-f4c0-4bf9-9f94-4d00bd445c16.aspx